# How can I get the average elevation for an area in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, elevation, area

I have got .tif file for a country and a dbf file which divides the country area into 42 subunit. I want to get the average elevation data for each subunit in meters.

Comment: Welcome! What software are you using?

Comment: Hi, QGIS 2.18.13

Comment: The dbf file is associated to a vector file? If so, use [Zonal statistics plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively easy to do in two steps:

1. Convert your dbf into a shp of polygons. To do so, you can use the
   tool **Line to Polygon**. This should be enough if lines from dbf
   are closed.
2. SAGA: **Raster statistics for polygons**. In this tool you
   you just need to specify the grid (raster) and the polygons (your
   new shp) where statistics will be calculated. You can choose between
   several things (mean, sd, count...), in your case just select
   "mean".

The result is a shp with a new collumn with the raster statistics.